# Single ASP.NET solution that handles multiple ports

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to specify different ports for a single ASP.NET solution? I'd like to have one solution handling requests coming in on multiple ports, but returning responses that are specific to each port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your site in IIS to set multiple bindings with different ports. Then in your app use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port` to determine the port and respond accordingly.